# intellij idea buddy plugins spring data jpa + rest repositories

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa, buddy.com

entity Class Project

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "manager_id", nullable = false)
private AppUser manager;
```

i have a problem when i create AppUserRepositories
post json :

```
{
    "name":"deoakw12",
    "manager":{
        "id":"1"
    },
    "tasks":[
        {
            "name":"oooo",
            "assignee":{
                "id":"2"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"oooo1",
            "assignee":{
                "id":"2"
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

message

> "not-null property references a null or transient value :
> com.jpa.buddy.entities.Project.manager"

Comment: when i delete AppUserRepositories ,that is ok

Comment: Please show us at least some code what you do